# Java : When does corresponding memory come into existence for local variables?

Tags: java, c

Does the variable declaration in java also allocate a space to the variable?

For example:

`String i;`

I cannot use `i` until I assign a value to it. But, do I already have memory for `i` allocated on stack after this line? Or, does it come into existence only when I assign it some value?

For example in C, this code would declare and also define the value on stack.

`int i;`

Is there some standard for this specified for Java? If not, what do compiler implementations typically do?

Comment: Yes it will create memory also for java.

Comment: Yes. The space for the local variable is allocated when the method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying

```java
String s;
```

in Java is analogous to saying

```c
char* s;
```

in C.

Space is allocated on the stack for a *pointer*, but not the actual contents of the `String` (which are of course not known at this time)